# How can I stream files to my iPad?

Tags: ipad, wifi, streaming

I have loads of videos and music on my computer, which I want to watch on my iPad.

However, I want to stream it to it, so I can grab what I feel like watching rather than having to preload everything.

I would like to stream these over wifi and they should be Windows 7 compatible

Answer (score 7):

I'm very happy with [Air Video](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/index.html)(*). Lifehacker have a [feature on it](http://lifehacker.com/5516405/air-video-streams-any-video-to-your-ipad-is-the-best-3-ive-spent-in-the-app-store).

(*) Have only used it on an iPhone, no iPads in Sweden yet :-(

Comment: Planning to try this one @Nifle, but waiting for my credit card to arrive ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - They have a link to a free version on their homepage. Don't know how it differs from the full version though.

Comment: It only shows you three files in your folder, so you don't get access to all your content

Answer (score 2):

Try [StreamToMe](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/streamtome/id325327899?mt=8). It is free and works quite well.

Comment: Strange it says here that it's $2.99, guess I'll have to wait for my credit card to arrive

Answer (score 1):

[TVersity](http://tversity.com/) works great for me. Basically, you set up a home server (it's all web-based) and it will convert real-time. Seeking is a bit of an issue, though apparently they're working on it.

Comment: +1 because it works, but I'll have to test how well it does multimedia

Answer (score 1):

I use [SubSonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) to stream music from my library at home to my iPad (among other devices). It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Air Video works much fine on iPad like it's on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [ZumoCast](http://www.zumocast.com/) for quite some time now and like it. It's been stable on my Windows XP HTPC and streams to my iPhone and iPad are great. It transcodes all kinds of formats on the fly. I've yet to see an encoding or format trip it up.

One feature I quite like about it is it'll transcode and store the stream to the media on my phone. So I can set it up at night, on my phone, to bring down a bunch of transcoded video files and have my own in-flight entertainment on the plane in the AM.

It should also let to stream when you're off of your home network but I don't ever use that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this won't be what you are looking for, but this is what Apple's Home Sharing is more or less designed to do. You'd just have to make sure all of the music and videos are imported into iTunes and that iTunes is running on the computer and the iPad and iTunes are using the same Apple ID.

Here's Apple's "Understanding Home Sharing" page:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819

Answer (score 0):

the best apps using smb protocol to play video audio and show photos pdf and downdload if you want or just stream

1. remote files
2. remote files free (pro)
3. fileexplorer

for video audio player only

1. aceplayer
2. oplayer
3. moliplayer hd

Comment: "Best" is usually relative, it will make the answer more useful for others if you add some details about what you like about these apps. Also links would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised to not see [Plex](https://plex.tv) mentioned yet.  Plex is both a media server, front end GUI for watching on a computer and mobile app for streaming content from your media server.  It is extremely straight forward to set up both for at home use and remote streaming via a free Plex account.  The computer version is free and the iOS app is $5.

You can download Plex for your PC at https://plex.tv/downloads and Plex for your iOS device at https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/plex/id383457673?mt=8

I've used both for 3-4 years now, often to watch content stored at home while traveling, with little to no complaints.

With that said.  I know that Plex can connect to your iTunes library and play it through the home theater interface but I don't know that this same functionality is present in the iOS app.

Answer (score -1):

[Audiogalaxy](http://www.audiogalaxy.com/) works great, but is for audio only.