# How to stream .avi and .rmvb files from Mac or PC to iPad?

Tags: ipad, streaming, vlc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stream files to my iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/how-can-i-stream-files-to-my-ipad)

There is a VLC app on the iPad, except it says, "enter your email address and we will email you the instruction" and that sounds fishy...

It also talk about using Bonjour, but I set up Bonjour on the PC and the iPad's VLC is still scanning and scanning and can't find it.

The final goal is to view any .avi or .rmvb files on the Mac or PC.  VLC is good with that.  I wonder what solutions there are on the iPad.

Comment: There is an app Air Video (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-video-watch-your-videos/id306550020?mt=8)

Comment: Already answered [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/how-can-i-stream-files-to-my-ipad)